# Is it possible to load a different kernel and jump into it from a kernel module?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, bootloader

There are some android devices (e.g. the Motorola Defy) with locked bootloaders. You can gain root rights on them, and you can even load kernel modules, but it's not possible to change the kernel that will be loaded initially. So, my question is:

Would it be possible to write a kernel module that loads another kernel into RAM, disables all interrupts, disables the MMU and then jumps into the new kernel image? Could that work, or would some already-initialized devices mess up everything?

Comment: You may check out the [Monte](http://monte.sourceforge.net/) project for starters

Comment: @AndreyErmakov: Woooah, looks good! :)

Comment: @AndreyErmakov: However, that's for x86 only, right? For the android stuff, the same would be needed for ARM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic mechanism for doing this in linux is kexec

Looks like someone has made what you seek work for at least once motorola phone:

http://www.xda-developers.com/android/kexec-bootloader-bypass-released-for-motorola-droid-razr/

Comment: Hmm, thanks... and at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=24918641&highlight=defy#post24918641 it says that the radio chip of the defy can't be rebooted... meh.

Comment: @thejh - don't reboot the radio chip then ;-)

Comment: Yes, exactly what I think. :D